# find method of the set

Tags: c++, stl, set

What exactly find method of the standart set returns? Iterator to the actual element in the set or to its copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns an iterator pointing to the actual element in the set

From table 69 in standard 23.1.2/7

**expression**

> a.find(k)

**assertion/note pre/post-condition**

> returns an iterator pointing to an
>   element with the key equivalent to k,
>   or a.end() if such an element is not
>   found.

Answer (score 1):

Iterator to the actual element or `end()` if not found